# Variable release after raising exception in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, except

I have some code as follows:

```
class A:
    def __del__(self):
        print('del A')


class B:
    def foo(self):
        a = A()
        raise RuntimeError


b = B()
try:
    b.foo()
    print('after b.foo() 1')
except RuntimeError:
    print('catch error')

print('after b.foo() 2')
```

The output is:

```
catch error
del A
after b.foo() 2
```

My questions are:

1) It seems that `a` is deleted after exception handling. Can anyone please help explain the order of the variable release in such cases?

2) How can I manually release variable `a` at the beginning of `except RuntimeError` block?

Some more words about the use case:

I would like to catch a CUDA out of memory error raised in `B.foo()` and release some `a` (some variables taking too much CUDA memory) at the beginning the `except RuntimeError` block. Then I can split the data to smaller pieces and do it again.

Comment: Please show your actual code. I think when CUDA is involved it's different than the normal garbage collection

Comment: You might want to add pycuda tag if thats what you are using

Answer (score 0):

Make `a` a attribute of your `B` instance and delete it:

```
class B:
    def foo(self, num):
        self.a = A()           # make it an attribute so you can access it from outside
        if num > 20:
            raise RuntimeError


b = B() 
try:
    b.foo(42)
    print('after b.foo() 1')
except RuntimeError:
    del b.a                    # now you can explicitly delete it
    print('catch error')
    b.foo(18)                 
    print('after b.foo() 1a')

print('after b.foo() 2')
```

If would probably be cleaner to use a `test_memory(self, data)`  and iterate on that until true, then proceed.

Not sure if the above approach works with CUDA.

Comment: Thanks Patrick! This partly solves my problem. However, do you know if there is any way I can just release variables in all the broken function calls in the current call stack? Because sometimes `a` is not own by 'B.foo' but by functions called by `B.foo` in some deep level. It is not very convenient to add attributes recursively in my call chain.

Comment: @Bo nope not familar enough with CUDA

Comment: @BoLi maybe post it as self-answer then and yours in 1-2 days :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a solution. [`traceback.clear_frames`]
(https://docs.python.org/3/library/traceback.html#traceback.clear_frames) does the magic.

```
import sys
import traceback
class A:
    def __del__(self):
        print('del A')


class B:
    def foo(self):
        a = A()
        raise RuntimeError 


b = B()
try:
    b.foo()
    print('after b.foo() 1')
except RuntimeError:
    exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
    traceback.clear_frames(exc_traceback)
    print('catch error')

print('after b.foo() 2')
```